# How to set the width of a group of bars in a bar graph?

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I've been using plotly.js for about a year now, and I have never seen this problem before. I am trying to plot the data per hour, and for this set of data, the information is only existent for this one hour. The lines are so thin, I haven't figured out how to make them wider or how to set the interval to be per hour. Right now it is set to per millisecond for this chart, and this chart only.

How it looks now.
[image: image 1]

Zoomed In View. This shows how it is being spaced out by millisecond.
[image: image 2]

How it should look. This is from another set of data. But as you can see they are spaced out per hour.
[image: image 3]

Edit: [Here is the paste bin link](https://pastebin.com/XN5aAWuQ) for those interested in the code.

```
<div id="report-<%= loc_i %>-<%= dev_i %>" </div>

<script>
  let instance = <%= raw(@instance.to_json) %>;

  (()=> {
    instance.locs.forEach((loc, loc_i) => {
      
      loc.chargers.forEach((dev, dev_i) => {
        console.log(dev);
        if (dev["stats"].length === 0) return;
        var trace1 = {
          x: [],
          y: [],
          name: 'data 1',
          type: 'bar'
        };

        var trace2 = {
          x: [],
          y: [],
          name: 'data 2',
          type: 'bar'
        };

        var trace3 = {
          x: [],
          y: [],
          name: 'data 3',
          type: 'bar'
        };


        dev["stats"].forEach(stat => {
          let date = stat['date'];
          let time = stat['start_time'];
          let dateTime = `${date} ${time}:00`;
          let data1 = stat['data 1'];
          let data2 = stat['data 2'];
          let data3 = stat['data 3'];

          trace1['x'].push(dateTime);
          trace1['y'].push(data1);
          trace2['y'].push(data2);
          trace3['y'].push(data3);
        })

        trace2['x'] = trace3['x'] = trace1['x'];

        var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

        var layout = {
          barmode: 'group',
          legend: {
            font: {size: 12}, borderwidth: '1', orientation: 'h',
            x: 0.5, y: 1.025, xanchor: 'center', yanchor: 'bottom'
          },
          xaxis: {
            title: 'Graph Title',
            range: [new Date(instance['start_date']), new Date(instance['end_date'])]
          },
          yaxis1: {
            range: [0, instance['graph_max']]
          }
        };

        Plotly.newPlot(`report-${loc_i}-${dev_i}`, data, layout);
      })
    })
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add the code you used to generate these plots? That would go a long way in helping people debug the issue

Comment: Thanks, I have added the code to the post.

Answer (score 2):

I have only found out how to do this using
`fig.update_traces(width=2000000)`
The 2000000 is arbitrary but is a good suit for my data which is hourly granularity. You can adjust to suit yours.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a width property to the trace object. this can be a number or an array of numbers. if its a number the same width is applied to all the bars. if its an array the width at ith index is given to the ith bar.

```
        var trace1 = {
          x: [],
          y: [],
          width:[], //here
          name: 'data 1',
          type: 'bar'
        };
```